# Actualizar datos de una tabla con condicion de porcentaje sobre precio existente

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Soy nueva en el tema de Procedimientos almacenados en Sql Server y necesito realizar un Update en una tabla.
Debo actualizar el precio de un producto pero el nuevo precio no puede estar por debajo ni por encima del 5% del precio actual del producto.
Estoy pensando en usar ( if y else ) pero nose como usarlo de manera correcta.
La verdad me quede en el siguinte codigo.

```
create proc Pr_UpdatePrecioProducto
(
@IdProducto int,
@PrecioUnidad money
)
as
begin
DECLARE @ValorActual INT
select [PrecioUnidad] from Productos where IdProducto = @IdProducto
if (@PrecioUnidad > 5% )
```

Answer (score 1):

No tienes porque hacerlo así, ya que algo condicional lo puedes aplicar en el where de la sentencia update.

```
create procedure Pr_UpdatePrecioProducto
(
  @IdProducto int,
  @precio money
)
as
begin

UPDATE Productos SET PrecioUnidad = @precio
    WHERE 
        (
        @precio <= PrecioUnidad * 1.05
        And
        @precio >= PrecioUnidad * 0.95
        )
        And
         idProducto = @IdProducto;

/* Si deseas devolver información al usuario, de que no se ha actualizado   ningún registro.
*/

if (@@ROWCOUNT=0)
    PRINT('No se ha actualizado ninguna fila'); 
end;
go
```

Solo actualizas el producto si el precio que le pasas como parámetro, esta comprendido en el rango de un 5% más o menos del precio actual.

Comment: Es funcional, pero con este update el usuario no se enteraría si se omitió el update, minimo deberia volver a preguntar por los @row_count para avisarle al usuario

Comment: Gracias @ronpy por la anotación.

Answer (score 0):

Podes validarlo antes de realizar el update, si no hay errores actualizas:

```
create proc Pr_UpdatePrecioProducto
(
@IdProducto int,
@PrecioUnidad money
)
as
begin
    if exists (select PrecioUnidad + (PrecioUnidad * 5 / 100) from Productos where IdProducto = @IdProducto) < @PrecioUnidad
    or exists exists (select PrecioUnidad - (PrecioUnidad * 5 / 100) from Productos where IdProducto = @IdProducto) > @PrecioUnidad
    begin
        raiserror(N'No puedes superar el 5% del precio original', 16, 1);
        return;
    end

    update Productos set PrecioUnidad = @PrecioUnidad where IdProducto = @IdProducto;
end
```